# Has anyone seen this error in Terraform Azurerm Frontdoor?

Tags: https, terraform, endpoint

Seeing this error on my TF logs, after apply. The resource looks ok but trying to understand what it means.

```
(Resource Group ""): unable to enable/update Custom Domain HTTPS for Frontend Endpoint "" 
(Resource Group ""): waiting to enable Custom Domain HTTPS for Frontend Endpoint: Code="None" Message=""
```

Comment: Seems there is a bug with Terraform and the portal where the https settings of a front end point are not updated in the portal if you update it via Terraform. Also, there is an error coming up with this message, they are also looking at it "Error: flattening `backend_pool`: ID was missing the `healthProbeSettings` element". They hope to have it done this week or the next one.

Answer (score 1):

For context, there's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8208) confirming that it's an Azure API bug due to case sensitivity.

Meantime fix to get Terraform files working would be to dowgrade to `2.23.0` prior to changes applied in `2.23.0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Azure, MSFT working on fix.